# MVC Razor loading spinner issue - spinner disappears before page fully loads

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, loading, onload

I'm working with MVC 5/Razor views. Want to display a spinner wheel until the page fully loads. This is in the Index load (no ajax involved).

The issue I'm having is that the spinner displays but then disappears before the page is fully loaded. The reason I'm saying the page isn't fully loaded is that it's still unresponsive (can't scroll, cant click dropdownlist or any other controls, etc.). I want the spinner to display until the page is responsive.

I'm using window.load, but I've also tried window.onload and document.ready. I have also tried it with text only in the div (no image).

```
<div id="divLoading">
     <h5>Loading.....<img src="~/Content/Images/loader.gif" alt="Loading...." /></h5>   
</div>

javascript:
$(window).load(function () { $("#divLoading").fadeOut("fast"); })
```

Comment: This appears related to IE11 actually. When I use Chrome or Firefox, the page doesn't encounter the long "unreponsive" pause. Only happens in IE for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Closing question since I found out its an ie11 thing. Leaving the answer in case anyone encounters the same issue. Try it in chrome or firefox, should be good to go. Ie gets hung up waiting for a response for some reason. You can see this in the ie11 debugger.